# Change target.extend code to comply with magento2.4.4 standard

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.4

In the process of upgrading magento commerce from 2.3.5 to 2.4.4p2

During checkout

Encountered this error at console

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')`

The origin of the error comes from this code on line 19

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'SR_ModifiedCheckout/js/model/address-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry'
], function(
    $,
    addressValidator,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    checkoutData,
    registry
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
// line 19
        return target.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'SR_ModifiedCheckout/address'
            },

            /**
             * @inheritDoc
             */
            setShippingInformation: function () {
                if (
                    this.validateShippingInformation()
                    &&
                    addressValidator.validateBillingInformation(this.isFormInline, this.source)
                ) {
                    registry.async('checkoutProvider')(function (checkoutProvider) {
                        var shippingAddressData = checkoutData.getShippingAddressFromData();

                        if (shippingAddressData) {
                            checkoutProvider.set(
                                'shippingAddress',
                                $.extend(true, {}, checkoutProvider.get('shippingAddress'), shippingAddressData)
                            );
                        }
                    });

                    setShippingInformationAction().done(
                        function () {
                            stepNavigator.next();
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I think this error might be because magento2.4.4 library does not contain this method thus causing the error

anyone know how do I rewrite the code to fix this

Comment: 2.4.4 OS version?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Sorry, OS = Open Source. Which magento version you are trying to?

Comment: Magento Enterprise ( Commerce ) version 2.4.4p2